# importing CocoalibSpotify in Xcode

Tags: ios, spotify

before I begin I'd like to point out I'm very new to coding and have a background in UI and UX design. However for a project I need to use Xcode and a music player, Spotify being the one of choice.

I downloaded the Spotify wrapper & Library files, and I got a developers key to make the sample files work but after this I really have no idea what to do with it.

I wanted the app to be as close to the iPhone's spotify app as possible, and with my limited coding knowledge wanted to know if there was an easy way for me to get  this in Xcode?

Any help would be great right now!

Thanks.

Comment: If you're very new to coding and you're not sure how to import the library, I recommend you explore Xcode and iOS Development a little more before you attempt to mimic Spotify's iPhone app.  They don't make the client app available for development, so you would have to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

CocoaLibSpotify doesn't provide the Spotify iPhone client in a package. It contains no UI elements at save for the login screen, which isn't the same as the one the official client uses.

However, CocoaLibSpotify *does* provide a foundation in which you can access a Spotify user's playlists and perform searches, etc. It also provides playback functionality.

To get started with CocoaLibSpotify, read the readme file — it includes instructions on how to get started in Xcode. Alternatively, look at the sample projects in the `iOS Library/Sample Projects` folder, which all include CocoaLibSpotify and a bunch of sample code to get you going.

Comment: Hi, I have read the FAQ but it only tells me what files i need to import?

It also says 'Once everything is set up, simply import the following header to get started with CocoaLibSpotify!

#import "CocoaLibSpotify.h"' Where exactly should i write this? And how do i go from that to being able to view my playlists?

Comment: CocoaLibSpotify is imported exactly the same was as every other third party library. Since CocoaLibSpotify requires a fair amount of Cocoa knowledge to use, it's assumed users are already familiar with what to do. Have a look at the sample projects - they'll show you what you need to do. The "Empty CocoaLibSpotify Project" project is something you can use to start your app - it's an empty app that has everything imported for you.

Comment: If I use the empty project file do I still need to follow the iOS FAQ? (frameworks and other linker flags) or is this already done?